# Setting up equations for colliding ellipsoids?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, collision

I can set up some equations for colliding spheres in D dimensions as follows. Let there be two spheres of mass $m$ and $M$ respectively. Let the first sphere have ingoing velocity vector $u$ and outgoing velocity vector $u'$. Similarly the second sphere has ingoing momenum $v$ and outgoing momentum $v'$. The balls collide tangent to an imagined hyperplane with normal $n$.

The equations are:

(1) Conservation of energy (1 equation):
$$mu^2+Mv^2 = mu'^2+Mv'^2$$
(2) Conservation of momentum in direction of normal (1 equation):
$$n.(mu+Mv) = n.(mu'+Mv')$$
(3) Momementum is conserved perpendicular to collision normal independently for each sphere (2D-2 equations):
$$|n|^2(u-u') = n.(u-u') n$$
$$|n|^2(v-v') = n.(v-v') n$$

This gives 2D equations in which to find the pair of vectors $u'$ and $v'$.

I am trying to set up similar equations for a pair of colliding ellipsoids in D dimensions. This will involve having an antisymmetric angular momentum tensor $\omega^{ij}$ for each ellipsoid. I know the angular momentum must be conserved but not sure how to express this as equations. Additional information needed would be a vector $r$ which equals $p-x$ where $x$ is the center of the ellipsoid at collision and $p$ is the point of impact.

I'm finding it hard to find such a generalised equation in the literature. It is probably not too hard to set up though. (The objects need not be mathematical ellipsoids, just some extended object of some kind).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Collision of two ellipses**

- $\mathbf w_i~$ start velocities
- $\mathbf v_i~$ final  velocities
- $\omega_i=\frac{d\phi_i}{dt}~$ angular velocities
- $S_i~$ center of masses
- $\mathbf t~$ tangential direction
- $\mathbf n~$ normal direction
- $I_i~$ moment of inertia
- $dp~$ linear momentum

with

$$\mathbf w_i=w_{in}\,\mathbf n+w_{it}\,\mathbf t\\
\mathbf v_i=v_{in}\,\mathbf n+v_{it}\,\mathbf t$$

the equations:

towards the normal direction

$$m_1\left(v_{1n}-w_{1n}\right)=dp\\
 m_2\left(v_{2n}-w_{2n}\right)=-dp$$

and for elastic collision
$$v_{2n}-v_{1n}=-\left(w_{2n}-w_{1n}\right)$$

towards the tangential  direction

$$m_1\left(v_{1t}-w_{1t}\right)=0\\
 m_1\left(v_{2t}-w_{2t}\right)=0$$

for the rotations about the center of masses

$$I_1\,\omega_1=dp\,\rho_1\\
I_2\,\omega_2=-dp\,\rho_2$$

you have 7 equations for the 7 unknows

$$ v_{1n}~.v_{2n}~,v_{1t}~,v_{2t}~,dp~,\omega_1~,\omega_2$$

results

$$v_{1n} ={\frac { \left( m_{{1}}-m_{{2}} \right) { w_{1n}}}{m_{{2}}+m_{{1}}}}+2
\,{\frac {m_{{2}}{w_{2n}}}{m_{{2}}+m_{{1}}}}\quad,
v_{1t}=w_{1t}\\
v_{2n}={\frac { \left( m_{{2}}-m_{{1}} \right) {w_{2n}}}{m_{{2}}+m_{{1}}}}+2
\,{\frac {m_{{1}}{ w_{1n}}}{m_{{2}}+m_{{1}}}}\quad,
v_{2t}=w_{2t}\\
\omega_1=-2\,{\frac {m_{{2}}m_{{1}} \left( -{w_{2n}}+{ w_{1n}} \right) \rho_{{
1}}}{ \left( m_{{2}}+m_{{1}} \right) I_{{1}}}}\\
\omega_2=2\,{\frac {m_{{2}}m_{{1}} \left( -{w_{2n}}+{ w_{1n}} \right) \rho_{{
2}}}{ \left( m_{{2}}+m_{{1}} \right) I_{{2}}}}\\
$$